# findViewById returns null when moved into a library file

Tags: android, layout

I'm new to Java and Android. I have a piece of code that is used for multiple activities so I moved it into its own library .java file. However, now my findViewById return null where they used to return the right stuff when they were part of the main Activity file with onCreate() and setContentView() calls. How do I make it work inside my library?

Call from the Activity class:

helper.popupControl(getListView(), getBaseContext(), "on");

The code in the libruary:

```
public class Helper extends ListActivity {
public void popupControl (View v, Context context, String on_off) {
    Animation aFilm = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);  
    aFilm.reset();

    View vFilm = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.gray_out_film);

    if(vFilm==null) { 
        Toast maxToast = Toast.makeText(context, "View is null! "+R.id.gray_out_film+", View:"+v.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        maxToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        maxToast.show(); 
    } else {
        Toast maxToast = Toast.makeText(context, "View is not null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        maxToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        maxToast.show();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me and the solution was to delete the main.xml from the new project. Somehow it was interfering with the main.xml from the library project even though I was referring to the fully qualified name (ex: library.package.R.layout.main).

Comment: This was legit the solution. I don't know why this didn't have more upvotes but even for a answer in 2012, this really did the trick for me today!

Answer (score 1):

Call `Activity.setContentView(int resID)` before calling `findViewbyId()`

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do seems 'icky' but here's how it would be done.

You'll need to pass the `View` from the Activity...findViewbyId() is its Member function.

If you provide some sample code, i could be more helpfull.

Edit: Confused `Context` with `View`. Oops!

Comment: Why "icky"? Since when placing common code in a separate libruary is "icky"??

Comment: @user,For one, you're apparently creating an entire new activity to host your Helper functions, Does Helper Need to extend `ListActivity`?

Comment: @user, `getListView()` returns  a Listview...You are trying to find `gray_out_film` within a listview, hence its returning NULL. You'll need the `View` of the LinearLayout of the First Activity. (which im guessing is a ListActivity)

Comment: `View v = this.findViewById(R.layout.activity);` Should work, or try `getRootView()`...Sorry, i can't be of much help, i don't have access to my development machine as of now.

Comment: That doesn't work. But, c'mon - hasn't anybody ever needed to move some common code into a separate class and deal with the UI components?

Comment: of course, it's been done, i've done the same...I'll get a working code ASAP.

Comment: OK. Let me know when you do. This is a huge bottleneck for me and somehow I don't see any other postings anywhere online about something like this.