# Side effects of calling Activity.setContentView() twice in a row

Tags: android, android-layout, oncreate

In my app I needed to call `findViewbyId()` from both `onCreate()` and from `WebChromeClient.onCompletion()`. To avoid `findViewbyId()` [returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733872/findviewbyid-returns-null-when-moved-into-a-library-file/4096330#4096330) I resorted to calling `Activity.setContentView(int viewResID)` before calling `findViewbyId()`.

It works, but now I am wondering whether I may have created a "time-bomb" in my code down the road.

Are there any caveats that I need to keep in mind when doing something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no problem in doing so. You have to reinitialize references (every findViewById needs to be called again) and it might be troublesome if you do it A LOT of times, but it is not a time bomb at all.

Comment: Thank you! The only reason I am calling Activity.setContentView() more than once is because I need to call findViewById() for a particular view more than once. The tip for having to call again **every** findViewById is invaluable. Thanks so much.