# Two different layouts are not working on single activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i have two xml layouts with one activity i used setContentView() for calling them but when i call the second view it called but not working.
here is the code:
when i click the fok button the the second layout shows but the buttons on it are not working. please help

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_pas);
    setContentView(R.layout.forpasrest);

    fok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                fok.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(220, 215, 255));
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_pas);

                flag=false;
            }

    });

    fback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                fback.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(220, 215, 255));

                Intent intent = new Intent(ResetPasActivity.this,SignInActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
    });

    if(flag==false){

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                back.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(220, 215, 255));
                Intent intent = new Intent(ResetPasActivity.this,SignInActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This could help [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017428/switching-between-2-layouts-in-android-activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017428/switching-between-2-layouts-in-android-activity)

Comment: layouts are shown but when i tried to work on second layout there is the problem of clicking the buttons as code shows

Comment: when i call setContentView(second_layout) it shows fine but it is not working

Comment: I suppose that this is because `flag` is false when `onCreate` is called. So `ok.setOnClickListener` and `back.setOnClickListener` are never set. You will have to call these methods when `fok` is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a second activity for your second XML layout rather than trying to change the layout of a single activity. For details how to do this read [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Answer (score -1):

To add to sergiome's comment: You should initialize your `ok` and `back` buttons **AFTER** you have set your 2nd layout here `setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_pas)`. Here is the modified code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_pas);
    setContentView(R.layout.forpasrest);

    fok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buildSecondLayout();
            }

    });

    fback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                fback.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(220, 215, 255));

                Intent intent = new Intent(ResetPasActivity.this,SignInActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
    });
}

private void buildSecondLayout() {
    fok.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(220, 215, 255));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_pas);

    final Button ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonIdForOk);
    final Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonIdForBack);

    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            back.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(220, 215, 255));
            Intent intent = new Intent(ResetPasActivity.this,
                    SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

The flow of your code seems pretty messed up, I don't even know how to explain the problem to you. Anyway, try the code to see if it works for you.

Comment: The preferred solution is to use a second activity.

Comment: why the downvote? I think there is nothing wrong with calling setContentView twice. as a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808026/side-effects-of-calling-activity-setcontentview-twice-in-a-row

and just because you think your solution is better and your reputation is higher doesn't give you the right to downvote mine. My answer is working and the only thing he wants to see is a solution to his code that is not working.

Comment: "why the downvote?" Because I consider this answer as "not useful" since it promotes bad programming practices. Creating two separate activities is much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: I simply provided a modified version of his code. If you wish to add a better answer, then explain it thoroughly so he would understand. PROVIDE your code too. and while you think your answer is better, it's doesn't even show a solution to the real problem which is his code's flow. Your solution is a mere suggestion/improvement/change to my answer and nothing else. You should downvote your answer insted.

Comment: thanks for the help both of you and both methods are working perfect.